# Grab a part of text when it matches, get rid of the rest because it's useless

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, text

I have a text called

```
string path = "Default/abc/cde/css/";
```

I want  to compare a text.

```
string compare = "abc";
```

I want a result

```
string result = "Default/abc";
```

The rest of the path `/cde/css` is useless.Is it possible to grab the desire result in asp.net c#. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you looking for?:

```
string result = path.Substring(0, path.IndexOf(compare)+compare.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This will loop through the different levels (assuming these are directory levels) until it matches the `compare`, and then exit the loop. This means that if there is a folder called `abcd`, this won't end the loop.

```
string path = "Default/abc/cde/css";
string compare = "abc";
string result = string.Empty;
foreach (string lvl in path.Split("/")) {
    result += lvl + "/";
    if (lvl == compare)
    {
        break;
    }
}
if (result.Length>0)
{
   result = result.substring(0, result.length-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string path = "Default/abc/cde/css/";
string answer = "";
string compare = "abc";

if (path.Contains(compare ))
{
     answer = path.Substring(0, path.IndexOf(stringToMatch) + compare.Length);
}
```

Something like the above should work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that if you meet questions of this kind in the future, you should try it yourself first.

```
string result = path.Contains(compare) ? path.Substring(0, (path.IndexOf(compare) + compare.Length)) : path;
```